# Сохранение позиции Player в 2d раннере юнити c#

Tags: c#

В игре, меню паузы реализовано через отдельную сцену (я знаю что я идиот), но на поздней стадии уже не хочется переделывать все сначала. Так вот, мне надо чтобы позиция игрока сохранилась при переходе с меню паузы на саму игру. Сейчас позиция сохраняется только при выходе из игры

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SaveXYZ : MonoBehaviour

{
public Scene Scene;
void Start()
{
if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("PosX") && PlayerPrefs.HasKey("PosY") && PlayerPrefs.HasKey("PosZ"))
{
transform.position = new Vector3(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("PosX"), PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("PosY"), PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("PosZ"));
}
}

private void OnApplicationQuit()
{
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("PosX", transform.position.x);
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("PosY", transform.position.y);
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("PosZ", transform.position.z);
}

}
```